Is there a way to manually refresh lightning-record-picker query results?
I am trying to use lightning-record-picker to obtain records of ServiceAppointment object. Records need to be filtered by by list of ids that are obtained from Apex method that is called as soon as recordId is set.
It seems that the component loads values only once before this.serviceAppointmentIds is populated with values and do not refresh when they are loaded.
Is there any way to manually refresh the component or maybe I'm just doing something wrong?
JS
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
  getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
    if (currentPageReference) {
      this.recordId = currentPageReference.state.recordId;
      this.getRelatedServiceAppointmentsByTimeSheetId();
    }
  }
@track serviceAppointmentIds = [];
renderLookup = false;

@track
  serviceAppointmentsFilter = {
    criteria: [
      {
        fieldPath: "Id",
        operator: 'in',
        value: this.serviceAppointmentIds
      }
    ]
  }



getRelatedServiceAppointmentsByTimeSheetId() {
    getRelatedServiceAppointmentsByTimeSheetId({timeSheetId: this.recordId})
      .then(serviceAppointments => {
        this.serviceAppointmentIds = serviceAppointments.map(serviceAppointment => serviceAppointment.Id);
        this.renderLookup = true;
      })
 }

HTML
<template if:true={renderLookup}>
            <lightning-record-picker
                    label="Service Appointment"
                    placeholder="Search Service Appointments..."
                    object-api-name="ServiceAppointment"
                    filter={serviceAppointmentsFilter}
                    required
            >
            </lightning-record-picker> 
        </template>


You set up serviceAppointmentsFilter so this.serviceAppointmentIds is used to initialize a property within it. If the content of that array changes, the @track will ensure refresh happens. However, you are changing the array reference in this.serviceAppointmentIds within the getRelatedServiceAppointmentsByTimeSheetId function, so the array in serviceAppointmentsFilter simply remains as-is, and you have a new array in this.serviceAppointmentIds.
You can either make sure to update the content of the referenced array, so populate the original array with new entries, or ensure that getRelatedServiceAppointmentsByTimeSheetId updates serviceAppointmentsFilter as well. This latter is easier to do:
getRelatedServiceAppointmentsByTimeSheetId() {
    getRelatedServiceAppointmentsByTimeSheetId({timeSheetId: this.recordId})
      .then(serviceAppointments => {
        this.serviceAppointmentIds = serviceAppointments.map(serviceAppointment => serviceAppointment.Id);
        this.serviceAppointmentsFilter.criteria[0].value = this.serviceAppointmentIds;
        this.renderLookup = true;
      })
 }

